# GraphX Vertices populated with Null values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am trying out a code in Spark GraphX and having difficulty with Null.

```
scala> verticesRDD
res76: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, (String, Long))] = MapPartitionsRDD[78] at map at <console>:51

scala> EdgesRDD
res77: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[Boolean]] = MapPartitionsRDD[18] at map at <console>:41

val graph = Graph(verticesRDD, EdgesRDD).cache()

scala> graph
res75: org.apache.spark.graphx.Graph[(String, Long),Boolean] = org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.GraphImpl@9533103
```

If i pull the vertices properties i am getting some null values.

```
val x = graph.vertices.map{case(id, v) => v}

scala> x
res78: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Long)] = MapPartitionsRDD[149] at map at <console>:56

scala> x.filter(_ == null).count()
res79: Long = 8999
```

Where as in the source verticesRDD there is no NUll.

```
val x = verticesRDD.map{case(id,v) => v}

scala> x
res80: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Long)] = MapPartitionsRDD[151] at map at <console>:54

scala> x.filter(_ == null).count()
res81: Long = 0
```

I am not able to understand why vertices values can be null when in source RDD for vertices there is no null in the values?

i would be really helpful if you could provide some insight about this.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*When `VertexIds` of `verticesRDD` and `EdgesRDD` don't match, then a null vertex is created for the non matching vertexId*. And thats the reason you have null in the `Graph` despite the fact that you don't have null in `verticesRDD`.

It will be more evident with simple example

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.graphx._

scala> import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

scala> val verticesRDD: RDD[(Long, (String, Long))] = sc.parallelize(Seq((0L, ("Subhasis", 0L))))
verticesRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, (String, Long))] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:28

scala> val EdgesRDD: RDD[Edge[Boolean]] = sc.parallelize(Seq(Edge(1L, 0L, true)))
EdgesRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[Boolean]] = ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at parallelize at <console>:28

scala> val graph = Graph(verticesRDD, edgesRDD)
graph: org.apache.spark.graphx.Graph[(String, Long),Boolean] = org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.GraphImpl@5563a63f

scala> graph.vertices.foreach(println)
[Stage 2:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 4](1,null)
(0,(Subhasis,0))
18/04/20 08:26:22 WARN Executor: 1 block locks were not released by TID = 9:
[rdd_9_3]
18/04/20 08:26:22 WARN Executor: 1 block locks were not released by TID = 8:
[rdd_9_2]
18/04/20 08:26:22 WARN Executor: 1 block locks were not released by TID = 10:
[rdd_9_0]
18/04/20 08:26:22 WARN Executor: 1 block locks were not released by TID = 11:
[rdd_9_1]

scala>
```

You can clearly see that `(1,null)` is created *for non matching vertexId of EdgesRDD in the graph*

I hope the explanation is clear and helpful

Comment: I think i figured, wanted to comment earlier but had to rush. In my edge rdd i have a mapping with a - b. where as in my vertices RDD i have information about a and not b. Thanks for your answer.